# launch a query from command prompt

Tags: windows, oracle, cmd, sqlplus

I have an Oracle 12c instance installed on my desktop, on Win 7.
I am trying to launch a trivial **SELECT** statement from **COMMAND PROMPT** and I expect to receive the result.

The code I am using is:

```
@ECHO OFF

ECHO *****************************

ECHO     Database Login

ECHO *****************************

@echo select 44 from dual | sqlplus username/password@SID

pause
```

When I execute this line, the cmd is opened and is stays on this screen

[image]

as it tries to connect to Oracle.

After a while, it show me the error below.

[image]

I am trying to connect from sqlplus with same credentials and everything works fine.
I am trying to launch sqlplus from command prompt, providing the username and pass and it works fine.

The problem appears when I launch the code from a .bat file.

Comment: Sounds like your bat file isn't inheriting the whole environment or is setting something that overrides the environment, perhaps. Incidentally, if you change it to `sqlplus -l` then it will exit after the first error, and won't try to use the `select ... ` text as login credentials, which is what's causing the secondary SP2 error. (Later you might want to add `-s` too which suppresses the banner, but only when the rest is working.)

Comment: Also you only referred to username and password when talking about running SQL\*Plus manually; are you using exactly the same command with the same connection string, particularly the (same) `@SID` part?

Comment: Yes, I am using same connection string

Comment: Then you seem to be picking up a different, or can't find from .bat, `tnsnames.ora` file. The `SID` is a TNS alias that it's looking up in that file. Maybe you have multiple files, and you picking up different versions depending on where you try to connect from (e.g. a copy in the current working directory)?

Comment: Use cut & paste to copy the content of the console windows into your question. Don't use images.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see images, but - aren't you lacking in command terminator?

```
                             | THIS!
                             v
M:\>@echo select 44 from dual; | sqlplus scott/tiger@kc11g

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on ╚et Kol 2 12:23:55 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL>
        44
----------
        44

SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

M:\>
```

**[EDIT: ORA-12154]**

It appears that the database you're trying to connect to doesn't exist in TNSNAMES.ORA file. See what happens when I'm connecting to "kc11g**xxx**" - ORA-12154, just like you:

```
M:\>@echo select 44 from dual; | sqlplus scott/tiger@kc11gxxx

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on ╚et Kol 2 12:36:23 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

Therefore, add it to TNSNAMES.ORA.

Comment: It is not from semicollon(;).
I receive the error: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified.

Comment: I edited my message with another example; have a look.

Comment: The database is defined in TNSNAMES.ORA

Comment: But, is that TNSNAMES.ORA in use? If there are multiple Oracle software installations on your computer, each of them contains its own copy. Can you verify that? If that's the case, consider using the **TNS_ADMIN** environment variable which points to a directory that contains TNSNAMES.ORA you maintain, and put all your databases in there. No need for other TNSNAMES.ORA files, then. Besides, what is the result of running (at the OS command prompt) `ping that_database_name'?